# Question about line.length();

Tags: c++

does line.length();  include end line chars?

For example

Hello World

How long would this be 11 or 12?

Comment: What is `line`?  Is it a `std::string`?

Comment: This depends on the code you use to construct `line`.  If you post it, you will get an answer.

Comment: What did you get when you try to run the program?

Comment: You could have run a test in the debugger in half the time it took you to post the question.

Comment: There is no end line character in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string s1 = "Hello World\n";
std::cout << s1.length() << std::endl;
```

This prints 12. The new line is included in the length.

Answer (score 3):

yes end line character( '\n') will be counted in the length.

```
std::string s = "Hello World";
std::cout<< s.length()<<std::endl;
s = "Hello World\n";
std::cout<<s.length()<<std::endl;
```

result will be

```
11
12
```